# Converting string to ascii and ascii to string

Tags: c#

I am giving the input to console program as "Hai My Name is KrishNA" and that string is converted in to ascii characters and I'm getting output as 543777096. I want If I give the same number as input I want the same output as above in the same program and for space the ascii value is 32 i want to skip that space.I wrote the c# program Below

```
string s1;
s1 = Console.ReadLine();

byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s1);
int result = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
//foreach (int r in bytes)
//{
Console.Write(result);

//}
//byte[] array = new byte[result];


byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s1);

foreach (int a in buffer)
{
    Console.WriteLine(buffer);
}
```

please help me on this

Comment: So you get the first 4 bytes of the characters ("Hai "), drop the rest and convert it into a 32 bit integer. What did you expect?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
string s1;
s1 = Console.ReadLine();

byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s1);
int result = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
Console.WriteLine(result);

String decoded = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
Console.WriteLine("Decoded string: '{0}'", decoded);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not convert a string to single 32 bit integer number, in your program, the number 543777096 represents "Hai " (include space), so you can not convert that number back to the first string. Use loop to convert each 4 characters to Int32 number, so your string should be represented by an array of Int32 number.

Answer (score 0):

It is completely unclear what are you use the `int` result for.

If you want to print the numbers to the console (or into a text file) use a string instead.

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s1);
string result = bytes.Aggregate("", (acc, b) => (acc.Length == 0 ? "" : acc + ", ") + b.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(result);

// prints 72, 97, 105, 32, 98, 108, 97, 98, 108, 97 for "Hai blabla"
```

If you want to leave the spaces out, you can filter the `bytes`:

```
result = bytes
         .Where(b => b != 32)
         .Aggregate("", (acc, b) => (acc.Length == 0 ? "" : acc + ", ") + b.ToString());
```

For longer input texts you should use a `StringBuilder` instead.